# body tag seen an element of the same type

Tags: html, validation

the w3 validator checker says, that my body Tag an element of the same type was already open.

> Error: Start tag body is seen, but an element of the same type was already open.

How have my Html Code,

```
</style>
</head>
<header></header>
<nav id="navs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="axxx.php">Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="xx.php">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Windows</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="Windows_10.php">Windows 10</a>
                <a href="Windows_8.php">Windows 8</a>
                <a href="Windows_7.php">Windows 7</a>
                <a href="Windows_xp.php">Windows XP</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="new-link">
            <a href="#" class="neuen">News & More</a>
            <div class="new-content">
                <a href="#">News</a>
                <a href="#">Geek</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<body>
```

All code [here](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&showoutline=yes&showimagereport=yes&doc=https%3A%2F%2Flinuxusers.net%2Findex.php#l1473c69)

Can please anyone help me with this problem, Thanks!

Comment: Look at the last line `<body>` tag is open but I don't see the close tag `</body>`. Check your code again

Comment: @Ivan — The end tag for the body element is optional, and the error message is not complaining about a missing end tag.

Comment: @Ivan,  I do not forget close tag </body>, it is downstairs where the code end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The start tag of the `<body>` element is optional so the `<body>` element is implicitly created when you use an element that *must* appear in the body.

In your example, `<header></header>`.

i.e. in that context, `<header></header>` means the same as `<body><header></header>`.

Consequently, when you get to `<body>` at the end, the element is already open.

Move `<body>` to the *start* of the body.

Comment: "The start tag of the <body> element is optional so the <body> element is implicitly created when you use an element that must appear in the body."  I do it and now not to come to this warning...                           Very Thanks! , I don't knowledge it.

Comment: can a question your asked?